# How to count the number of leading zeros in all 32 bit parts of md5 hash

Tags: python

I want to take the md5 hash of a string and return the number of leading zeros in each 32 bit part of it. So for example:

```
import hashlib
print(bin(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"a").digest(), 'little')))
```

gives:

```
0b1011101101001000111011101010111110000101011101111000000010111001011100100100111001111100000101001111100011101111100001101010011101001101110111000010001110011010101100110011000111000010111110101100101010111101000110111100101000010010100000011001011111001010
```

Ignoring the "0b" at the front, there are sixteen 32 bit numbers in the hash.  I would like to return the number of leading zeros for each one of those. So in this case it should be:

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3
```

I can process the bit string but I am not sure it's really the best way given the goal. Maybe I should be using hexdigest instead?  Using `bin` looks like it might be the wrong approach.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be a fancy binary way to go about this, but since you already have a string of zeroes and ones, just skip through every 32 characters and figure out where the first `1` is from that starting index:

```
import hashlib

hex_digits = bin(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"a").digest(), "little"))[2:]
offsets = [
    hex_digits.index("1", offset) - offset
    for offset
    in range(0, len(hex_digits), 32)
]
print(offsets)
```

outputs

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
```

---

## About those fancy binary ways...

Since we don't have easy access to a native `clz` instruction, let's borrow [the `clz3` function from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#CLZ)...

```
import hashlib
import timeit


def clz3(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 32
    n = 0
    if (x & 0xFFFF0000) == 0:
        n = n + 16
        x = x << 16
    if (x & 0xFF000000) == 0:
        n = n + 8
        x = x << 8
    if (x & 0xF0000000) == 0:
        n = n + 4
        x = x << 4
    if (x & 0xC0000000) == 0:
        n = n + 2
        x = x << 2
    if (x & 0x80000000) == 0:
        n = n + 1
    return n


def offsets_clz_1(int_val):
    clzs = []
    while int_val:
        chunk = int_val & 0xFFFFFFFF
        int_val >>= 32
        clzs.append(clz3(chunk))
    return clzs[::-1]


def offsets_bin_string(int_val):
    hex_digits = bin(int_val)[2:]
    offsets = [
        hex_digits.index("1", offset) - offset for offset in range(0, len(hex_digits), 32)
    ]
    return offsets


int_val = int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"a").digest(), "little")
assert offsets_bin_string(int_val) == offsets_clz_1(int_val)
print(timeit.Timer(lambda: offsets_bin_string(int_val)).timeit(1_000_000))
print(timeit.Timer(lambda: offsets_clz_1(int_val)).timeit(1_000_000))
```

On my machine, just letting Python do its thing with bit strings is faster:

```
bin_string: 2.09820
clz_1:      3.51417
```

Comment: I was wondering if using `bin` was needed at all. Do we really need to make a string?

Comment: I added one non-stringy approach, but it's slower (likely due to arithmetic being done in Python). If you need the performance, you could use Cython to turn this into a more optimized native extension.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire code will be :

```
import hashlib
temp = bin(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"a").digest(), 'little'))[2:]
result = [len(temp[32*i:])-len(temp[32*i:].lstrip('0')) for i in range(int(len(temp)/32))]
print(result)
```

Comment: This prints the wrong answers. It should give 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3 .

Comment: That was a misunderstanding :) sorry! This works now. But @AKX did it faster. I will vote him up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitwise operators:

```py
import hashlib
my_hash = int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"a").digest(), 'little')
print(bin(my_hash))
for i in range(7,-1,-1):
    for bitPos in range(31,-1,-1):
        if 2**(i*32+bitPos) & my_hash:
            break
    print(31-bitPos)
```

Comment: Turning `2 **` into `1 <<` makes this about 3 times faster :)