# python: efficient way to check for leading zeros in a bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for an efficient way to check for leading zeros in a bytes object. The check should run also for nibbles. Right now I am checking bytes only, with the `search_zeros` function; where the input parameters are: `n`: number of leading zeros to check for, and `inp_bytes` the bytes object:

```
def search_zeros(inp_bytes, n): # inp_bytes is always 20 bytes
    if n % 2 ==0:
        bytes_to_check = n // 2
        check_bytes = bytes(bytes_to_check)
    else:
        # check for nibbles?
        return
    if inp_bytes[:bytes_to_check] == check_bytes:
        return inp_bytes 

print(search_zeros(b'\x00\x002\xe04\x83\xb1.)\x1c\x17\xa5\xb7u\xcc\n\xb0\xfdg0', 2))
>>>b'\x00\x002\xe04\x83\xb1.)\x1c\x17\xa5\xb7u\xcc\n\xb0\xfdg0'

# How to check for nibbles?
print(search_zeros(b'\x00\xe04\xe04\x83\xb1.)\x1c\x17\xa5\xb7u\xcc\n\xb0\xfdg0', 1))
>>> None
```

I was reading about bitwise operations, and I am trying to familiarize with the topic. Could this be applicable here?

EDIT

I know I could use `.startswith(b'\x00')` but is there a faster way to do it?

Clarification:

The function should return `inp_bytes` if it starts with exactly `n` zero nibbles, no more no less, otherwise it should return `None`.

Comment: `.startswith(b'\x00')`?

Comment: I don't understand how the question relates to the code.

Comment: `check_bytes = bytes(bytes_to_check)` ? Your code and your question are both unclear.
is `n` supposed to be the expected number of leading zeroes?

Comment: This question I just answered seems vaguely relevant... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67229010/how-to-count-the-number-of-leading-zeros-in-all-32-bit-parts-of-md5-hash/67229071#67229071

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga please see the edit

Comment: Your function is a bit strange: do you intend to return `inp_bytes` if is has the leading zeroes, and None otherwise?

Comment: On the nibbles part of your question, what's the Endianness of your definition of "leading zeroes"? I.e., which of `b'\x00\x03'` and `b'\x00\x30'` do you consider has 3 leading zeros, and which has two?

Comment: @joanis The first one has 3 leading zeros, the second one has 2

Comment: @joanis Yes, that is exactly what I want, and what the function does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid constructing `check_bytes`, since that will consume unnecessary storage in memory when n is very large. So my approach would be to use a loop or an equivalent comprehension.

Additional considerations:

- I assume you don't want an exception if the string is too short, so I added some logic for that case. I think `len(inp_bytes)` is a constant time operation, so this should be fast.
- I'm using the fact that a byte `y` is "True" when non-zero, I'm pretty sure that's as fast a way as any, but benchmarking could confirm that if you're really after all the nanoseconds you can save.
- You can use bitwise operations to test the last nibble if `n` is odd. Note that in Python, bitwise operations are defined on bytes, but not in sequences of bytes. `b'\xf0'` is a sequence of bytes, so `& b'\xf0'` yields an exception. `b'\xf0'[0]` is the first (and only) byte in that sequence, and that's accepted as an operand of `&`.
- EDIT: you clarified in the comments you only want `inp_bytes` returned if the number of leading zeros exactly equals `n`--logic added to check that the next nibble is non-zero.

With all that in mind, this is my solution:

```py
def search_zeros(inp_bytes, n):
    if len(inp_bytes) < (n+1)//2:
        return None
    if any(y for y in inp_bytes[:n//2]):
        return None
    if n % 2 != 0 and inp_bytes[n//2] & b'\xf0'[0] != 0:
        return None
    # Make sure the next nibble is not zero:
    if n % 2 != 0:
        if inp_bytes[n//2] & b'\x0f'[0] != 0:
            return inp_bytes
    else:
        if len(inp_bytes) == n//2 or inp_bytes[n//2] & b'\xf0'[0] != 0:
            return inp_bytes
    return None


x=b'\x00\x00\x03\x44'
for n in range(10):
    print(f"n={n} x={x} result={search_zeros(x, n)}")

x=b'\x00'
for n in range(5):
    print(f"n={n} x={x} result={search_zeros(x, n)}")

x=b'\x00\x10'
for n in range(5):
    print(f"n={n} x={x} result={search_zeros(x, n)}")

x=b'\x00\x01'
for n in range(5):
    print(f"n={n} x={x} result={search_zeros(x, n)}")
```

output:

```
n=0 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=1 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=2 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=3 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=4 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=5 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=b'\x00\x00\x03D'
n=6 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=7 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=8 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=9 x=b'\x00\x00\x03D' result=None
n=0 x=b'\x00' result=None
n=1 x=b'\x00' result=None
n=2 x=b'\x00' result=b'\x00'
n=3 x=b'\x00' result=None
n=4 x=b'\x00' result=None
n=0 x=b'\x00\x10' result=None
n=1 x=b'\x00\x10' result=None
n=2 x=b'\x00\x10' result=b'\x00\x10'
n=3 x=b'\x00\x10' result=None
n=4 x=b'\x00\x10' result=None
n=0 x=b'\x00\x01' result=None
n=1 x=b'\x00\x01' result=None
n=2 x=b'\x00\x01' result=None
n=3 x=b'\x00\x01' result=b'\x00\x01'
n=4 x=b'\x00\x01' result=None
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So,  It should be always `n>1`. For the input `b'\x00\x00\x03\x44'` only `n=5` should return the bytes. All the other should return `None`

Comment: Oh, you want it to start with exactly n zeros, no more no less! That's not what your code does as it is...

Comment: Then you'll have to add a check that the next nibble is non-zero, if that's what you want.

Comment: So when the `inp_bytes` has no leading zeros the function should return always `None` it does not matter what is the value of `n`

Comment: The function returns the `inp_bytes` only if  `n` is equal to the number of the `inp_bytes` leading zeros

Comment: That's it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler bit of code that implements the same logic in a way that is much easier to understand: count the leading zeros, then test if that number is equal to `n`. I'm posting it as a different answer because it's not a refinement, it's a very different solution.

Optimization included: stop counting zeros at n+1, so we don't scan a string with an arbitrarily large number of leading zeros further than necessary.

```py
def count_zeros(inp_bytes, max_count):
    """ Count the leading zero nibbles in inp_bytes, up to a maximum of m """
    result = 0;
    for y in inp_bytes[:(max_count+1)//2]:
        if not y:
            result += 2
        else:
            if y & b'\xf0'[0] == 0:
                result += 1
            break
    return min(result, max_count)

def search_zeros(inp_bytes, n):
    """ return inp_bytes iff it has n leading zero nibbles """
    if count_zeros(inp_bytes, n+1) == n:
        return inp_bytes
    else:
        return None
```